# "Run-time error '58': File Already Exists" - Access Database

Tags: runtime

I keep getting this error message `Run-time Error '58': File Already Exists`. The code it highlights as error is: `fso.movefile SubmittedFile, LoadedFile`.

Please see below for full code:

```
 Set MyWorkbook = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(InputDir + ImportFile)

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Gift Disclosure New Load")
    Set MySheet = MyWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MySheet.Activate
    With MySheet
'        .Unprotect            'Remove user interface protection
'        .Range("A1:AA6000").Locked = False        'Unlock cells
    End With
    With rst
        .AddNew
        .Fields("PrimaryBaseCode").Value = MySheet.Range("H10").Value
        .Fields("AdvisorName").Value = MySheet.Range("H11").Value
        .Fields("FirmProvidingGifts").Value = MySheet.Range("H12").Value
        .Fields("RepProvidingGifts").Value = MySheet.Range("H13").Value
        .Fields("GiftDescription").Value = MySheet.Range("H14").Value
        .Fields("DateOfEvent_Text").Value = MySheet.Range("I15").Value
        .Fields("DateOfEvent_Date").Value = MySheet.Range("H15").Value
        .Fields("OtherInfo").Value = MySheet.Range("H16").Value
        .Fields("FileName").Value = MyWorkbook.Name
        .Update
    End With
    rst.Close
    CurrentBook = MyWorkbook.Name
    MyWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    ImportFile = Dir
    FileCount = FileCount + 1
    SubmittedFile = InputDir & CurrentBook
    LoadedFile = OutputDir & CurrentBook
    fso.movefile SubmittedFile, LoadedFile
Loop
MyExcel.Quit

Set fso = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery "01_Get EmailSender"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "02_Get EmailSubject"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "10_Load New Record to Master"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
MsgBox "New files are loaded."
End Sub
```

Comment: Before you do the "moveFile", check to see if the file already exists at your destination location.  If it does, then try to delete it and if the delete is successful, then do the move, if not, then you have a locked file and you need to handle that situation.

Comment: works perfect! thank you!